# How to avoid scroll to last focused element on Toast close

Tags: lightning, scrolling, toast

I'm using a Toast for showing whether a search has successfully completed or not when clicking the "Search" button.

My problem is that, when it shows the list of results and I'm scrolling along it, when the toast duration is over (or even if I manually click on the X ), it automatically scrolls to the latest focused/clicked DOM element, which is the Search button on the top of the page.

This is a really annoying behaviour. Can anybody help me out on that? (I'd love to avoid using jQuery, by the way)

Thank you really much!!

Comment: You find any solution/workarround? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding "mode: 'pester'" stopped the auto-scroll after close. It also removed the close button, and did not actually perform like documented "remains visible until the close button is clicked", instead behaving more like sticky, "remains visible for 3 seconds"